# (@event.start_date-Time.now) // NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In this app when an event is created the system checks whether is closer than 3 days. If it is, it changes a boolean value.

It was working fine but I do not know what I have done but the substracting operation gives me an error.
NoMethodError (undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass):

I am sure is a simple mistake.. but cannot find it. Any help much appreciated. Thanks a lot!!

event_controller.rb

```
  def create
    categories = params[:category_ids] or []
    @event = Event.new(params[:event].merge(:user_id => current_user.id, :category_ids => categories))
    check_date

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        #Mailer to seek appoval
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private 

  # Set the event to 'reminded'
  def check_date
    if close_date
      @event.reminded = true
    end
  end

  # Checks whether an event is happening in less than 72h
  def close_date
    if ((@event.start_date-Time.now)< 259146.01469397545)
      true
    else 
      false
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently the date fields are empty when the event tries to be saved. And this is because I changes the fields to implement dateTimePicker.

They used to be

```
.field
    = f.label t :event_start_date
    %br
    = f.datetime_select :start_date
  .field
    = f.label t :event_finish_date
    %br
    = f.datetime_select :finish_date
```

And now
field

```
    = f.label t :event_start_date
    %br
    = f.text_field :start_date, :class=>"datetime_box", :size=>"17"
  .field
    = f.label t :event_finish_date
    %br
    = f.text_field :finish_date, :class=>"datetime_box", :size=>"17"
```

Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Your `@event` must not have `start_date` set. Also, consider using `72.hours` instead of that huge constant (with a strange number of decimal places...)

Comment: mmh... you might be right. Just realized that I changed something at somepoint because dates are not stored anymore. Let me see...

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer, then.

Comment: @SergioNekora What is the Date format in the DateTimePicker (so in the `params[:event][:start_date]`)? What is the supposed format you want?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you ask. But the Date format should be 'datetime'

Answer (score 0):

Your `@event` must not have start_date set.

Also, consider using `72.hours` instead of that huge constant (with a strange number of decimal places...)

Comment: As you were right I have updated my questions with the problem